# stream error handling in pipe - stop the previous stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, stream

I am trying to handle the error event correctly with pipe function.

Given that I have two stream A (transform stream.passThrough()) and B(writeStream) in a Promise,  code is as follows:

```
new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
               A.pipe(B).on('error', (err)=>{reject})
                         .on('end', ()=>{resolve})})
```

The above code rejects the promise as expected, However, stream A is keep working. Can someone suggest me how to stop stream A flowing?

Answer (score 0):

You could DESTROY the stream A when an error occures :

> **`transform.destroy([error])`** Destroy the stream, and emit 'error'. After this call, the transform stream would release any internal resources. Implementors should not override this method, but instead implement readable._destroy(). The default implementation of _destroy() for Transform also emit 'close'.

**EDIT**

```
new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
               A.pipe(B).on('error', err => { A.destroy(); reject(err); })
                         .on('end',    e => { resolve(e) })
})
```

Comment: I have tried to pause the stream but it is still flowing. A is a passThrough type stream.

Comment: Since `passThrough` streams are implementations of `Transform` streams, you should be able to call `A.destroy()`

Comment: is still flowing. Could it bc A is a result of other streams?

Comment: I have no idea, i'll try to look into it